# Pandas interpolation /MSE

Tags: python, pandas

I know that there is an easy solution for my problem with pandas (hopefully) but I just don't know how to find it. Let's say I've two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 3], 'y1': [1, 4, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': [1.5, 2, 3.1, 3.9], 'y2': [1, 3, 5.5, 8]})
```

I want to calculate Mean Square Error and standard deviation between those 2 curves. I thought I could make an interpolation by joining those 2 dataframes with only one axis "X" containing both x1 and x2, and two axis "Y1" and "Y2" containing y1 and y2 values and interpolated values.

I can do it with loops but I'm pretty sure it must be some way easier with Pandas. Do you have any idea ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your desired output and how you've done it with loops?

Comment: Hey Pault, thank you for the answer :) . I actually didn't do it with loops yet, I'm just wondering if there is an easy way before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to bring them to a common grid (abscissa) in order to perform the subtraction and the statistics on it.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 3], 'y1': [1, 4, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': [1.5, 2, 3.1, 3.9], 'y2': [1, 3, 5.5, 8]})
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['df1', 'df2'], index=np.linspace(0, 4, 100))
df['df1'] = np.interp(df.index, df1.x1, df1.y1)
df['df2'] = np.interp(df.index, df2.x2, df2.y2)
print("MSE = {}".format(np.sqrt((df.df1.values**2 - df.df2.values**2).mean())))
print("STD = {}".format((df.df1.values - df.df2).std()))

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

That would produce the output

```
MSE = 4.051003878995869
STD = 1.1595280634334968
```

And the plot of the values[image]

Note that I used a sampling of 100 points which should be enough for your case.